# Attach Files to Mandrill Message with Browse Button

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, input, mandrill

I'm not sure whether this is even possible, but I'm trying to attach a file to an outgoing email with the [Mandrill API](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html) from the file upload button (`input type="file"`). To be honest, I'm not entirely sure what `document.getElementById('idOfFileInput').value` actually returns. I know that this is not the place to ask a novice question like that, but I've looked everywhere and I can't find it (I know one of you will be sly and point me to some article within five minutes). That aside, though, I've gotten a .txt file to attach with the message `C:\fakepath\test.txt`, which I know to be the file path that the browser gives for security. Maybe it's better asked in code:

Button:

```
Attachment(s):&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="file" id="file">
```

JS:

```
"attachments": [
        {
            "type": "text/*",
            "name": "file_attachment",
            "content": document.getElementById('file').value
        }
    ],
```

I'm sorry if this is a simple question disguised by its context, but even if it is, I have a feeling that this question could be a good future reference because I've been trying things for a week and looking for some type of solution, but I haven't been able to find one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wanted to attach a file, you could look at AJAX file Upload

The Mandrill API requires a base64 encoded string of the file, so if you can upload the file you can easily make the server return a base64 encoded string for you to use in the API..

There are lots of plugins that will upload files over ajax and if you're using a JavaScript library like jQuery you can look at [**jQuery File Upload**](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)

If you're using **PHP** for instance:

```
$result = array();
$result['status'] = 'error';
if(isset($_FILES["mandrill_attachment"]))
{
    $base64 = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["mandrill_attachment"]["tmp_name"]));
    $result['base64'] = $base64;
    $result['status'] = 'ok';
}

die(json_encode($result));
```

I've kept that short for the example, but you should check the file types etc, not just assuming it's an OK file

and the **JS**

```
var mandrill_attachment = false;

$(".attachment").uploadFile({
    url: "upload.php",
    dragDrop:false,
    multiple:false,
    autoSubmit:true,
    fileName: "mandrill_attachment",    
    returnType:"json",
    onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr)
    {
        if( data.status == 'ok' )
        {
            mandrill_attachment = data.base64;
        } else {
            alert('something went wrong...');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at this extensively, and it appears that it's impossible to use file upload input with the Mandrill API for attachments. A server is required to do anything with a `file type="input"` because of the security restrictions that have been put into place by browsers.

I've been able to get around this by using the [Ink File Picker API](http://www.inkfilepicker.com) to place a secure download link at the bottom of the email to a file, but this looks a little fishy. It it would obviously be better to do it natively, but, as I've said, that appears to be impossible.

This compromise, however, is in some ways *better* than the native way: the Ink API allows users to upload from a variety of services, along with the classic file upload, which improves both the extensibility and the ease of use of the file upload mechanism.

Using a link for attachments still looks suspicious, but I've been able to minimize the spamminess of the method by using the file name (which the API gives you access to):

> [file name] (hyperlinked to direct download link) was attached to this
>   email.