# JavaScript selecting image to an img tag

Tags: javascript, html, image, image-uploading

I have a fake profile system for a class project, it requires a profile picture, and it needs an option to change it locally (from your hard drive). I have a working `img` tag that holds a placeholder image as a default, and when you click `change picture`, an open file dialog opens. All I need to work now is setting the image link for the `img` tag with the image they selected. This is what I have so far.

```
<div id="userphoto">
    <a><div class="gravatar-wrapper-128"><img id="image" src="http://blog.ramboll.com/fehmarnbelt/wp-content/themes/ramboll2/images/profile-img.jpg" alt="" class="logo" width="120" height="120"></div></a>
    <div class="change-picture-slide" style="top: 30px;">
        <input accept="image/*" type="file" id="upload" name="upload" style="visibility: hidden; width: 1px; height: 1px" />
        <a href="" onclick="changePicture(); return false">Change Picture</a>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function changePicture() {
        //open the open file dialog
        document.getElementById('upload').click();
        var link = document.getElementById('upload').url;
        //change picture
        var img = document.getElementById("image");
        img.src = link;
    }
</script>
```

Knowing this can not be done, how could I have the image the user selected be uploaded anonymously to [imgur](http://www.imgur.com/) and using this link?

Comment: This is not possible, as it would be a major security issue. See this existing question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav

Answer (score 7):

You can try this by using file reader in javascript.

```
<div id="userphoto">
        <div class="gravatar-wrapper-128"><img id="image" src="body-img.jpg" alt="" class="logo" width="120" height="120"></div>
        <div class="change-picture-slide" style="top: 30px;">
            <input accept="image/*" type="file" id="upload" name="upload" onchange="readURL(this);"style="visibility: hidden;" />
            <a href="" onclick="changePicture(); return false">Change Picture</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function changePicture(){
            $('#upload').click();
        }
        function readURL(input)
        {
            if (input.files && input.files[0])
            {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e)
                {
                    $('#image')
                    .attr('src',e.target.result);

                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }



    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the native file uploading interface ([as I've found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025414/attach-files-to-mandrill-message-with-browse-button)) doesn't allow you to do that, assuming you're only working client-side.

The only time that `<input type="file"/>` will ever be useful to you is in a `form` that is submitted to a server because browser security measures prevent you from doing anything else with it.

Modern browsers will give you a fake file path on the client side as the result of a file upload to prevent malicious acts with the user's filesystem.

However, I think the [Ink Filepicker API](//filepicker.io) provides exactly the functionality you're looking for. When the user uploads a file, it will return an object that contains the name of the file and a *URL that points to its download location*, which is exactly what you're looking for (this would fill the `src` attribute of your image).

It's really simple to set up, actually.

First, sign up for a free account and grab an API key. In your `head`, set it up like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//api.filepicker.io/v1/filepicker.js"></script>
<script>filepicker.setKey('API_KEY');</script>
```

Then, you have access to all of the API's functionality.

To do what you're asking, you'll need to create a button like this:

```
<button onclick="handleFiles();">Upload Image</button>
```

Clicking on it will produce a dialog for the user to pick a file that looks like this:

[image]

Then, create a handler function:

```
<script>
    function handleFiles() {
        filepicker.pick({
            mimetypes: ['image/*'],
            //you can also define what uploading services you want to use here
        },
        function(e) { //you now have access to the file
            var link = e.url;
            //change picture
            var img = document.getElementById("image");
            img.src = link;            
        });
    }
</script>
```

I've found this to be a tremendously useful API: [here are the docs](https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/docs/web/).

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/P6gtw/)

Answer (score -1):

I believe the code is:

```
var link = document.getElementById('unpload').value;
```

Update after AstroCB's comment:

You could then use:

```
var link_split = link.split('\');
var link = link_split.length;
```

Or something similar I'm not 100% sure of the syntax maybe someone can help you out a bit more

Comment: This will give you `C:\fakepath\filename.extension` because of the security implementations put into place by browsers.

Comment: Or just `filename.extension`.

Comment: So if for security reasons you can't do this... how about uploading this file to imgur.com or something like than anonymously and using that?

Comment: I would suggest using PHP's upload function as it seems the best tool for your job. Using different websites to host your user images just seems messy.

Comment: @DrRoach From the question, it sounds like a client-side-only option is required here.

Comment: @AstroCB yes, PHP is very useful but is not aloud within this project.

Comment: Okay so that makes more sense now, I would suggest then that you do infact try and get the absolute path to the image so that no files need to be moved, all you need to do is know where the file is currently stored. This is your only possible solution really as javascript can only operate in your browser. In short, get the path eg. 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/images/chosen_image.jpg' either via your file input or a text input and set this to your image source.

Comment: @DrRoach That's the problem; for security reasons, the real file path is obscured by the browser.

Comment: Oh really? Never knew that

Comment: @DrRoach Yes; you don't want to give a potentially malicious script access to your filesystem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath

Answer (score -1):

There's FileReader.readAsDataURL (see Indra's answer) and also window.URL.createObjectURL:

```
function changePicture() {
    //open the open file dialog
    document.getElementById('upload').click();
    document.getElementById('upload').onchange = function() {
        var file = this.files[0];
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
        document.getElementById('image').src = url;
    };
}
```