# getting the input[type=file] file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input-type-file

I have a problem with `<input type="file">`. I open the file selector and choose an image. I also have an `<img>` element, of which I want the `src` to be set to the chosen image. How can I do this using javascript (jQuery is fine)? The only thing I could find is that I am unable to get the path to the image; the value of the input will be `C:/fakepath/myimage.fileextension`. Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: You need JavaScript [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025414/attach-files-to-mandrill-message-with-browse-button

Comment: @AstroCB the related question says a server is required... What I want to do is part of a chrome extension (.crx) for a New Tab Page. This is  as far as I know all local files, does this mean it's impossible?

Comment: @vrugtehagel See the question that I've marked this as a possible duplicate of: it should have your answer.

Comment: google for a preview script